# Python: subprocess.Popen() running C++ code with input, "merge" with stdout

Tags: python, c++, subprocess

I have some code in C++ and Python. I'm designing some Python code to work as a "tester" for testing submitted C++ snippets. Let's say some of that code has the following form:

```
#include <iostream>
int main(){
    int a, b;
    std::cout << 'Enter a: ';
    std::cin >> a;
    std::cout << 'Enter b: ';
    std::cin >> b;
    
    std::cout << 'The result is ' << (a + b) << std::endl;
}
```

In Python, it takes the executable and feeds it inputs to the stdin in the form of a string, then pulls the stdout. It might look like this:

```
import subprocess

sample_input = '1\n2\n'
proc = subprocess.Popen(['./my_executable'], stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
                                             stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                                             stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
result = proc.communicate(bytes(sample_input))
proc.wait()

print(result[0].decode('utf-8'))
```

The output was expected to represent exactly what's on the terminal, which would look like this:

```
(*'a: 1\nb: 2\nThe result is 3\n*)

    $ ./my_executable
    a: 1
    b: 2
    The result is 3
```

But instead I just get the output without the stdin:

```
(*'a: b: The result is 3\n'*)

    a: b: The result is 3
```

How might I combine the output to match exactly what the terminal might look like? Notably, merging the stdin with the stdout as it happens?

The way I was thinking (probably terrible) was to individually send commands while capturing small snippets, and adding them as it goes. Which would be gross but feasible. Wondering if there's a better way.

Comment: sadly, feeding your subporocess' inputs chunk by chunk is the only way I can think of to simply achieve what you want. If the format of the inputs is simple and known in advance (newline-delimited, ...) you can parse the input (`str.splitlines()`) to do it. But in more difficult cases, it will get very hard very fast. You may reconsider how your C++ program is implemented.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I was afraid of... Unfortunately these code snippets are not created by me and I'm trying to automate the input/output sequence. Luckily, std::cin is only used for a few bits of code, then the rest are command line arguments.
Oh well, worth a shot by asking, thanks!